# Percentage Rows from Mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my model code that gets percentage of all questions in table (questions)

```
$public function ques()
{
   #get all question count
   $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
   $result = $query->result_array();
   $count = count($result);  

   $limit = ($count/100)*50;  

   # select only limited question which set with $limit
   $query= $this->db->get("Questions" , $limit);
   $result = $query->result_array();
   return $result;
}
```

There are four columns : 
1. ques_id 
2. question 
3. exam_id 
4. chapter

What I need that to get no of rows of each chapter and get percentage rows rather than to count all the questions only and returning result as shown in code. Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please can you rewrite this query including group by?

Comment: How about you give it a try, show what you come up with, and we can help from there. Also, it is always helpful to provide a sample dataset with expected results.

Comment: $query= $this->db->query("SELECT chapter, COUNT(*)
FROM questions
WHERE exam_id = 7
GROUP BY chapter");

but its not working :(

Comment: try $this->db->select('*')->from('questions')->where('exam_id', 7)->group_by('chapter')->get();

Comment: Am a little bit confused of you problem. Please give more examples.

Comment: There is no way if `$count` is equal to 2000 that `($count/100)*50` could be equal to 200.

Comment: #Tpojka  i have updated, now recommend answer